# Remove values from list element, and add to other element

Tags: list-manipulation

Basically what I need is to make a list of 400 elements, all have value 1. The next step is to create a function, that subtracts value (-1) from an element, and adds that to another element.

So: (1,1,1,1) could become (1,2,1,0).

Running the function 1 time is called a sweep.
The sum of the list has to be 400 at all times, and an element needs to have minimum value 0.

The function needs to make all elements ''exchange'' 1's with each other randomly.

(1,2,1,0) could also become (0,4,0,0) for example.

Comment: Sounds like a nice homework! Have you tried something?

Comment: Look up `Nest` and `ConstantArray`.

Comment: I tried 
f[a_] := list + RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, 400] + a - a

Where list is a list of 400 elements with value 1. But it is obviously to simple to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rough stab at it that should help you get started:

```
f[x_List] := Module[{n, lis = Range @ Length @ x, len = Length @ x, d = x},
  Do[(n = RandomChoice[lis, 2];
    If[d[[First @ n]] > 0, d[[First @ n]] -= 1; d[[Last @ n]] += 1]), {len}];
  d]
```

Now we generate our list of ones:

```
list = ConstantArray[1, 400];
```

Then:

```
res = f @ list
```

> ```
> {0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 
> 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
> 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 
> 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
> 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
> 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0, 3, 4, 1, 0, 
> 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 
> 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
> 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 
> 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
> 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
> 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
> 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 
> 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 
> 2, 0, 0, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 
> 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}
> ```

And:

```
Total @ res
```

> 400

Comment: Thanks for your quick and satisfying response. I am trying to understand all the steps you've used in order to understand the algorithms. Could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @a-es Sure. Assuming we use your smaller example with only 4 elements. `lis = Range@Length@x` creates a list from `1` to `4` (the length of the list). `len = Length@x` is the number of elements in the list. Now we pick randomly, the position of two elements from our list by `n = RandomChoice[lis, 2]`. Now the `If` statement does the subtraction of `1` from one element and addition to another element only if the first element is greater than `0`, so that we keep to your requirement of minimum value of `0`. The `Do` statement just repeats the process a certain number of times. Hope this helps.